# Laravel Jquery Ui Ajax Post to Controller and get value to blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I built and basic Jquery Ui slider:

```
    $("#sliderNumCh").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        step: 1,
        value: 20,
        change : function(e, slider){
            $('#sliderAppendNumCh').empty();
            var getSliderVal = document.getElementById('sliderValue').value = sliderValue;

            $('#sliderAppendNumCh').append(
            <div class=\"form-group\" style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\">
                ...
            </div>);

        },
        slide : function(e , slider){
            $('#number_of_chapters').val(slider.value);
        },
    });
```

My question is now how to post the slider value on each slide to my Laravel Controller.

I tried this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{Route('getAjaxRequest')}}",
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            data: {value: getSliderVal},
            success: function (option) {
                console.log(getSliderVal);
            }
        });
```

route:

```
Route::post('create', ['as' => 'getAjaxRequest', 'uses' => 'ProductController@getAjaxRequest']);
```

and in my controller I tried to call and return the value like this:

```
public function getAjaxRequest()
{
    $value =  Request::get('value');
    return view('productRom.edit')->with('value', $value);
}
```

so basically I want to get the slider value and later on return the value to a php function, to use that value for example in a loop.

I am not used to Ajax and therefor not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Edit**
I tried Jose Rojas suggestion:

```
public function getAjaxRequest()
{
    $value =  Request::get('value');
    //do your stuff
    return $slideValue;
}
```

And I get following error in the console:

> http://localhost/myapp/public/product/edit/%7BproductID%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)

the actual url is:

> http://localhost/myapp/public/product/edit/51

**Edit**

this is my route:

```
Route::get('edit/{productID}', ['as' => 'editProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@editProduct']);
```

Comment: you're posting variable to a method to set to other view?

Comment: yes so basically to use a javascript variable in php

Comment: put your ajax code in slide change option or slide option

Comment: it is inside the change option function, I get the error again if I slide :)

Comment: is it show internal serve error..?

Comment: what excatly do you mean? The Chrome Console shows me the error above

Comment: check your ajax code and url by inspect element what url made..?

Comment: sorry I do not get what you mean, the console just shows this error `http://localhost/myapp/public/product/edit/%7BproductID%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand well, you want to get the value for a slide so the method in your controller instead return a view should return the value for the slide, somthing like this:

```
public function getAjaxRequest($productID)
{
    $value =  Request::get('value');
    //do your stuff
    return $slideValue;
}
```

then, in your method that receives the value, you do what you want with this value. The goal of using AJAX is load parts of web page without reloading whole web page.

Comment: Thanks I cannot check this now, I will let you know tomorrow

Comment: I get following error in the console `POST http://localhost/myapp/public/product/edit/%7BproductID%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)`, thus this is always happening in a edit product with its id,
the actual url is `http://localhost/myapp/public/product/edit/51`

Comment: put your ajax code in  slide change option or slide option

Comment: @JohnDoe2 what is your current code at the controller, can you post it?, see the edit at the method you must specified as argument, parameters received thorugh URI

Comment: I just have a basics index-, new-, create-, edit-, destroy- methods for my products + the getAjaxRequest method

Comment: @JohnDoe2 according with your javascript code, `{{Route('getAjaxRequest')}}` AJAX request is pointing to the `create` route and not to edit. please check that.